# How do I saturate my upload and download available bandwidth?

Tags: python, bash, upload, download, bandwidth

As the question explain, I would like to saturate my bandwidth. For download I had an idea:

1. Download a random file (5MB for example) in **loop** for **n** time using **wget** or **urllib2**.
2. Delete the file each completed download, with the same loop.

(For wget using a Bash script / For urllib2 using a Python script)

But, I have two questions:

1. How do I saturate the **download** bandwidth **without** files downloading?
2. How do I saturate the **upload** bandwidth? (I have no idea in this)

I mean a **total** saturation, but if I want a **partial** saturating?

Comment: http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/ is a tool to degrade your connection. Maybe there is a way to saturate your bandwith.

Comment: start multiple wget , something like : nohup wget ...... &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just running a few wget's should easily saturate your download bandwidth.

For upload, you might set up a web server on your computer (carefully poking a hole through your firewall for it), and then connect to a web proxy (there are a few of these that'll anonymise your data) and back to your web server.  Then connect to your web server through the proxy and download (or upload!) a bunch of stuff.

It may be more effective to do these things one at a time, rather than both at the same time, as they may interfere with each other a bit.